# How to keep last n number of line from log file in php

Tags: php, logging, lines

I want to delete all lines from old log files and keep fresh 50 lines which is at the bottom.

How can I do something like this and if possible can we change the orientation of these lines,

```
normal input

111111
2222222
3333333
44444444
5555555

output like

555555
4444444
3333333
22222
111111
```

To see the fresh log at top and 50 or 100 lines only.

How to join it with this one?

```
// set source file name and path 
$source = "toi200686.txt"; 
// read raw text as array 
$raw = file($source) or die("Cannot read file"); 
// join remaining data into string 
$data = join('', $raw); 
// replace special characters with HTML entities 
// replace line breaks with <br />  
$html = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($data));
```

It made the output as an HTML file. So how will your code run with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$lines = file('/path/to/file.log'); // reads the file into an array by line
$flipped = array_reverse($lines); // reverse the order of the array
$keep = array_slice($flipped,0, 50); // keep the first 50 elements of the array
```

from there you can dow whatever with `$keep`. for example if you want to spit it back out:

```
echo implode("\n", $keep);
```

or

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/file.log', implode("\n", $keep));
```

Comment: +1 though he might run into memory issues when the logfiles are large

Comment: Thanks alot but how to join it with this one ? ,

    // set source file name and path
    $source = "toi200686.txt";

    // read raw text as array
    $raw = file($source) or die("Cannot read file");

    // join remaining data into string
    $data = join('', $raw);

    // replace special characters with HTML entities
    // replace line breaks with <br />
    $html = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($data));


it make the output as a html file, so how ur code will run with this properly ?

Thanks

Comment: I would think it would be better to get the array slice before flipping it, to avoid duplicating what could be a large array.  `$keep = array_reverse(array_slice($lines,count($lines)-$n-1, count($lines)-1))`.

Comment: yup that's right JeffB , but where to write 50 ? in that line ?
and i got that working ( prodigitalson )

Comment: The 50 goes in $n.  So... `$keep = array_reverse(array_slice($lines,count($lines)-51, count($lines)-1))`

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit more complex, but uses less memory as the entire file is not loaded into the array.  Basically, it keeps an N length array, and pushes on new lines as they are read from the file while shifting one off.  Because the newline is returned by fgets, you can simply do an implode to see your N lines, even with the padded array.

```
<?php
$handle = @fopen("/path/to/log.txt", "r");
$lines = array_fill(0, $n-1, '');

if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle);
        array_push($lines, $buffer);
        array_shift($lines);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

print implode("",$lines);
?>
```

Just showing another way to do things, especially if you don't have `tail` at your disposal.

Comment: +1 for this as well. Definitely less resource intensive... i just happen to avoid resource handles if at all possible :-)

Comment: i m confused now, tell me which one shud i use

Comment: @Mikeyy: Depends on whether memory is a concern.  Most likely it is not, considering these are text files, so either solution will work.

Comment: yea, so which is best, well i guess your's is the best one , i got all of these working :D

Comment: may you just help me with this one, i need reuglar expressions, preg_replace

want to remove the whole line depends on word2----

[word1] something-line-text [word2] some text again --
into -->
want to replace some text with another depends on word2--and

[word1] something-line-text [word2] some text again--into-->
REPLCACEDTEXT something-line-text some text again

Comment: @Mikeyy: You lost me.  I need a more specific description and/or an example.  This might be better asked as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

This would work for truncating the log file:

```
exec("tail -n 50 /path/to/log.txt", $log);
file_put_contents('/path/to/log.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $log));
```

This will return the output from `tail` in `$log` and write it back to the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Optimal form is:

```
<?
print `tail -50 /path/to/file.log`;
?>
```

Comment: sure does with Cygwin Tools installed. The problem with this approach is getting the newlines when writing back to the log

Answer (score 0):

this method use associative array to store only `$tail` number of lines each time. It does not fill the whole array with all lines

```
$tail=50;
$handle = fopen("file", "r");
if ($handle) {
    $i=0;
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle,2048);
        $i++;
        $array[$i % $tail]=$buffer;
    }
    fclose($handle);
    for($o=$i+1;$o<$i+$tail;$o++){
        print $array[$o%$tail];
    }
}
```